# How to remove Field Group module label length limit?

Tags: 7, entities

How to remove Field Group module label length limit (which is 128 characters). Is there any module to change the default length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this module [remove field length limit](https://drupal.org/project/remove_field_label_length_limit)

> - Removes field label length limit (which is 128 characters).
> - The module supports entity field labels and views field labels.

Or you could also write a custom module

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'your_form_id'){
    $form['your_field_name']['label']['#maxlength'] = 255;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this module but it is not changing the field module label length limit.

Comment: See update to my answer